# How to get list of browser shortcut keys

Tags: javascript

I am providing users to define their own shortcut keys in my application. The problem is I want to stop them creating shortcut keys(ex: "CTRL", "T" - two inputs from user) that are specific to browser. So I want to define an array of builtin browser specific shortcut keys so that I can validate user specified shortcut key input against this array and I will allow only if user input does not belong to this list.

Comment: when you're using JavaScript, there is no way to capture available shortcuts exposed in the browser’s accessibility tree. You can only make a list of reserved shortcut keys and then validate user input based on the list and prevent reserved shortcuts. You can find the whole list of chrome keys [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en) and [firefox shortcut keys](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly).

Comment: @MasLoo Thanks for the immediate response. I was looking for this list of reserved keywords

Comment: Hope it helps. Happy coding.

Comment: @MasLoo Can you please give me a link to get reserved shortcut keys for IE as well?

Also assume user supplied input  = "CTRL + SHIFT + N" and my reserved list contains "SHIFT + CTRL + N". In this case how can I match between supplied and reserved array?

Comment: [IE shortcut keys](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15357/windows-internet-explorer-11-keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: copy: Also assume user supplied input = "CTRL + SHIFT + N" and my reserved list contains "SHIFT + CTRL + N". In this case how can I match between supplied and reserved array?

Comment: It needs a little twist on your code. You could change list of shortcuts to a multidimensional array and convert user input to an array too, and then compare them. It's not the best way to do that but you can give it a try.